# Getting a list item with the max evaluation in a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Given this list of tuples:

```
my_tuples = [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

and the following evaluation function:

```
def evaluate(item_tuple):
    return item_tuple[0] * 2
```

**Question**: how can I get the list item (tuple) that has the highest evaluation value? (I'm guessing I can use a list comprehension for this)

---

```
def max_item(tuples_list, evaluation_fn):
    '''Should return the tuple that scores max using evaluation_fn'''
    # TODO Implement

# This should pass
assertEqual((3,4), max_item(my_tuples, evaluate))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it this way:

```
def max_item(tuples_list, evaluation_fn):
    zipped = zip(map(evaluation_fn, tuples_list), tuples_list)
    return max(zipped, key=lambda i:i[0])[1]
```

I don't know if there's a simpler (more pythonic?) way to solve it though.

---

*Edit*

I figured how I could use a list comprehension to make it more succinct/readable:

```
def max_item(tuples_list, evaluation_fn):
    return max([(evaluation_fn(i), i) for i in tuples_list])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want the list of tuples sorted by the result of multiplying one of the values inside the tuple with x (in your example above it would be the first value of the tuple multiplied by 2).

If so, you can do it this way:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0 * 2), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @MSKW, but that's not what I was after. I wanted a single item form the list (which happens to be a tuple in my case) that evaluates to the highest score according to a provided "evaluation function." Look at my answer and hopefully that'll make it clearer.

Comment: your list comprehension works of course but I'll give it one more shot before admitting I didn't understand the question well enough ;) 

```sorted(l, key=lambda x: evaluate(x), reverse=True).pop(0))```